# Python Linked Lists- Sorting between linked lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, linked-list, quicksort

Suppose I have an array, in which the elements are linked lists themselves, where the ordering is based on the highest element present in the list. The elements in the linked lists can be integers, floats or strings. So, the linked list which has the highest valued elements sits at the 0th position in the array after sorting.
How would I go about sorting between n such linked lists?

Comment: imaging how easier it would be for us to answer had you actually posted such a list as an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` with a `lambda` function search for the `max` of each linked list. For example

```
>>> l = [[1,7,3], [2,4,5], [0,9,3]]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda i: max(i), reverse=True)
[[0, 9, 3], [1, 7, 3], [2, 4, 5]]
```

This would work the same way if you had an array of linked lists as long as you could call `max` on the linked list.

Comment: Isn't the list in your example a nested list?

Comment: @user7091463 Yes, but until you show us what your "linked list" class looks like, I can't show you a solution using that, so I used a regular list as a proxy. Due to "duck typing" the solution should work the same way, which is why I mentioned your linked list class would have to allow the `max` method to work